# How do I log out from Google Apps without logging out from Android Device Manager?

Tags: security, device-administrator

Say my phone was stolen, and I need to log out from my Google Apps in that phone remotely. I can revoke the access in that phone through my web browser, however I would log out from Android Device Manager too and I won't be able to track it.

The only thing I guess it could work is to change Google's password, however I don't know if I will be logged out from Android Device Manager on that phone.

Comment: If you can, you should try to delete application data of Google apps. That will "log you out" or better set you in the state before you logged in. Maybe that will help you because no notifications/messages can be received if you are not logged in/no login/session token is available.

Comment: Thanks, but what do you mean by "set you in the state before you logged in"? I have to remotely (from web browser) log out from Google applications, without logging out from Android Device Manager, which must be logged in, in order to find my phone.

Comment: Deleting application data technically doesn't log you out but rather deletes your session token and asks for a new one upon trying to log in again.

Comment: Ok. It's a pity that there isn't a better solution than deleting my application data. I mean, it should be possible to log out from each Google app at once. However, Google offers you to unlink all your Google Apps from your Android device, including ADM.